# about order of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that an entire function of order fractional has an infinity zeros.

for example the function $f(z)=e^{\sqrt{z}}$ of order $\frac{1}{2}$ but it have no zeros in plan complex.

Could anyone explain for me?. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$e^{\sqrt z}$ is not an entire function. $\sqrt z$ has a branch cut.